# Is acyclic ZF consistent?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

I need to know if the following system is consistent, because I want to use it in presenting automorphisms over stratified versions of it.

The system I'd label as "*Acyclic ZF*", which is $\small \sf ZF-Reg.+ acyclic \ AFA + Rank$, is obtained by adding a two place predicate symbol $\mathcal R$ symbolizing *is the rank of* to the language of $\small \sf ZF$, then replace Regularity by the following two acyclic AFA axioms:

**Acyclicity:** $\forall x_1,..,x_n: \neg (x_1 \in x_2 \in x_3 \in ... \in x_n \land x_1=x_n)$

**Acyclic construction:** For every *acyclic* [accessible pointed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooted_graph#Set_theory) there exists a set whose membership graph is isomorphic to it, where the latter means the membership map on the transitive closure of that set.

Now we define the unary predicate  *ordinal*, symbolized by $\mathcal Ord$, as  *transitive set of transitive sets*. To be emphasized here is that an ordinal can be a von Neumann or may not be so! If the ordinal is well founded on $\in$, then it is a von Neumann ordinal, if not then its to be called as a non-standard ordinal, or even more outrageously an *ill-founded ordinal*. We make axioms to the effect that the ranking relation $\mathcal R$ constitute a partial function from ordinals to sets such that the indexed sets would correspond to iterative powers similar to the buildup of the cumulative hierarchy. Formally this is:

$\forall a,b,c,d: \mathcal R(a,b) \land \mathcal R(c,d) \longrightarrow [a=c \Leftrightarrow b=d]$

$\forall x: \exists y (\mathcal R (x,y)) \iff \mathcal Ord(x)$

$\forall \alpha \forall x \forall y: \mathcal R(\alpha, x) \land \mathcal R (\alpha \cup \{\alpha \}, y) \longrightarrow y=\mathcal P(x)$

$\forall \alpha \forall x [(\not \exists \beta: \alpha=\beta \cup \{\beta\}) \land \mathcal R(\alpha,x) \longrightarrow \\ x= \bigcup \{y: \exists \beta \in \alpha ( \mathcal R(\beta,y)) \}]$

$\forall \alpha \forall x : \mathcal R(\alpha,x) \to \alpha \subseteq x \land \alpha \not \in x$

$\forall \alpha \forall x: \mathcal R (\alpha, x) \to \forall y \in x (y \subseteq x)$

The last axiom is to restrict sets to those itrative stages, I'll consider it as a parallel to foundation, that is:

**Para-foundation:** $\forall x \exists \alpha \exists v : \mathcal R(\alpha, v) \land x \in v$

> Now, is Acyclic ZF consistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acyclic ZF is inconsistent. Let D be the directed graph whose vertices are the natural numbers where (a,b) is an edge if a=0 and a<b, or b>0 and a>b. By  Acyclic construction, there is set {x0.x1,x2,...} such
that xi∈j iff (i,j) is in D. Each xi is a transitive set and thus each xi is an ordinal.

(1)Suppose R(xi,yi) for all natural numbers i. Suppose j>0. Then every von Neumann ordinal is in yj.
Proof: Suppose it is not true and let b be the least von Neumann ordinal  which is not in yi for all i>0. We note that for i>0, xi=x(i+1)U{x(i+1)}. By our assumption, for every i>0, b⊆y(i+1). Therefore b∈yi.

Therefore there is a set A of all von Neumann ordinals. But then A is a von Neumann ordinal and thus A∈A.

Comment: D is a directed graph. What is the cycle?

Comment: Thank you for that answer. The graph you defined is *cyclic* so it won't apply. But anyhow you are right as far as regarding my intention behind developing this theory! It appears that in order to save this approach I must forbid $\mathcal R$ from appearing in separation and replacement.

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to have a rank that is both:

1. Ill-founded, and
2. successive steps are obtained by the power set operation.

The reason is simple, it would define a "Specker-tree" which is not a tree. Recall that $T$ is a Specker tree if it is a collection of sets such that $x$ is the direct successor of $y$ if and only if $|y|=|\mathcal P(x)|$. Specker trees are well-founded, in the sense that they do not have infinite branches.

The reason, of course, is that $x\mapsto\aleph(x)$ is a function which is non-decreasing with power sets, so an infinite branch would correspond to a decreasing sequence of ordinals. And even if you decide that all hereditarily transitive sets should be called "ordinals", it does not change the fact that Hartogs numbers are **well-founded** ordinals.

Comment: I think you want to say that $x\mapsto\aleph(x)$ is increasing with powersets, not just non-decreasing; otherwise I don't see how to get an infinite descending sequence of Hartogs numbers.

Comment: It's not increasing, because if $x$ is amorphous $\aleph(x)=\aleph(\mathcal P(x))$. The thing is that the tree is really going downards.

Comment: The point is, if $\aleph(\mathcal{PPP}(x))=\kappa$, then $\aleph(x)<\kappa$. Now consider the fact that a Specker tree is in a sense logarithmic when it "grows up", an infinite branch is necessarily a decreasing sequence in Hartogs numbers.

Comment: (You can probably get better gaps with Lindenbaum numbers, but it doesn't matter, does it?)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The definition of the Specker tree would be made inside a stage by using separation (or replacement), I think this definition would essentially use of the symbol $\mathcal R$ here. If we forbid using $\mathcal  R$ in instances of separation and replacement would that objection still hold.

Comment: Does that argument use choice?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar: Yes, it uses choice. That's why I go through Hartogs numbers and not just claim it is finite by Cantor's theorem. No. Of course it's not using choice.

Comment: your comment is paradoxical you said it uses choice and then you said not?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar: I'm sorry. I naturally assumed you'd understand sarcasm. No, choice is not needed here. If you look at the proof of Hartogs' theorem you'll find that it follows from it. And if you've used choice to prove Hartogs' theorem, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: why it is an open problem that one can have a Specker tree of infinite rank in absence of choice?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar: Because it's a nontrivial problem? Why is it an open problem whether or not the Partition Principle implies choice? Sometimes things are just hard.

Comment: I mean why this is not implying existence of infinitly descending hartogs coming down from a common node? I mean you say that the Specker tree cannot have any of its branches being infinite because the hartogs cannot descend down for ever, that's understood, but why it is not the same condition for the hartogs of all the end nodes of a tree, won't those be infinitely descending???

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar: Because trees can have infinite rank without having infinite branches.

Comment: Yes, of course, I know that. I'm speaking about the SET of the hartogs of ALL end nodes of a Specker tree with infinite rank. It appears to be a set of infinitely descending ordinals?

Comment: By the way, I think all of that happend because you allow the use of $\mathcal R$ in instances of separation and replacement. I think if we shun that, we can save the approach. Or do you have a proof that the same argument would still run.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar: The Hartogs can jump by an infinite gap when taking power sets, so there's room to grow from the roots, even if all have the same Hartogs.

Comment: I just wanted to say that: all of that only means that all ordinals are von Neumann's. So the theory is still consistent but not interestng. However, I think if we forbid $\mathcal  R$ from being used in separation and replacement, then possibly this can allow us to use ill-founded ordinals as ranks of stages, and even upgrad acyclic construction in the way used in Greg's answer. It's allowing the use of some ill-founded ordinals as indices of stages in an iterative hierarchy that is the whole purpose of this theory.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar: At this point you stopped even participating in this discussion. You seem to be under the impression that you can just avoid von Neumann ordinals altogether, like they don't exist somehow. I'm not sure why you even accepted the other answer, since it also uses those. Even if you remove $\mathcal R$, you cannot have an ill-founded "sequence" of iterated power sets. Period. This is my last comment on the topic, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I don't understand your last comment really. Yes, you cannot have this sequence internally, I agree, but you can have it externally. I thought that that what happens when we don't allow $\mathcal R$ in separation and replacement. Allowing the stages being indexed by ill-founded ordinals, doesn't mean by itself that you have that sequence internally in your theory (unless you use $\mathcal R$), if somehow it can be shown that this  sequence can exist internally even without using $\mathcal R$, then the whole approach fails).

Comment: continuation...If the website allows accepting two answers, I would have accepted BOTH, because both of them address the heart of the issue and they are the correct answers. I'm just saying that if we forbid using $\mathcal R$ then perhaps, this approach would be saved, we'd be having an *external* sequence of stages indexed by ill-founded ordinals, and this is pretty much standard, the real point of all of that is related to the automorphism question, this might allow us to use $j$ in separation and replacement but definitely not $\mathcal R$

Comment: hmmm... on second thought I'm realizing that the problematic factor (the one that causes ill-founded sequences) must be forbidden from comprehension axioms, so that the ill-founded sequence remain external, so here the culprit that I can see is $\mathcal R$, but if we add automorphism $j$ then that would be problematic also, since it's free use in comprehension axioms would cause internal forbidden sequences. I see.  so it must be shunned from comprehension axiom. It appears that this kills my approach. Thanks

Comment: one last remark, the purpose of this theory was to add automorphisms on stratified versions of it, and for that purpose this might work, because simply stratfication cannot handel von Neumann's.

Comment: Does this argument require Replacement? I mean the existence of a Hartog number for every set requires replacement. So if we work in Zermelo only, then would this still apply?